# I need an idea of pine script v5 code to show me last dot under 0 (which is a cross under in this case)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need a idea for my issue how to write a code in pine script v5 to help me to identify any last red dot (or Bear dot how I call it) under 0 line, no matter how many bars back happened already, printed on the indicator VuManChu Cypher B + Divergences, created by vumanchu, once VWAP(wtvwap is the ID) moved up instantaneous and on previous bar VWAP moved down. This VWAP is built-in this indicator.

I tried to find out something on internet, video or some articles, about this topic but no chances so far, so I decide to ask here maybe someone knows and has idea what about I am asking to solve my issue. I tried to use bar count codes but is no even close of what I need it. The red dot's code line is

`= ta.crossunder(wt1,wt2) and (barstate.islast or barstate.isconfirmed)`

Comment: Please include your entire script; we need to see a [mcve] to help.